# Jquery custom validation with Html 5 data attributes and default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to build a custom client side jquery validation and trying to ignore default values that i generate from HTML5 data attributes

```
   $('input, textarea').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('val-default')) {
                $(this).focus(function () {

                if (this.value == $(this).data('val-default'))
                    this.value = '';
            });
            $(this).blur(function () {
                if (this.value == '')
                    this.value = $(this).data('val-default');
            });
            this.value = $(this).data('val-default');
        }
    });
```

So with the above code i can add default values to input and textarea elements like this

```
data-val-default="Type your first name here"
```

Placeholder attribute is unfortunately not an option yet

The problem now is that i am trying to validate these elements with Jquery validation like this

`$.validator.addMethod("ignoreDefaultValues",
                            function (value, element) {
                                if ($(element).data('val-default'))
                                    return !($(element).data('val-default') ==          element.value);
                                return true;
                            },
                            "Required field"
      );`

```
$('form#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).valid({
                 rules:
                        {
                    title:
                        {
                            ignoreDefaultValues: true,
                            required: true
                        },
              description:
                        {
                            ignoreDefaultValues: true,
                            required: true
                        },
                     name:
                        {
                            ignoreDefaultValues: true,
                            required: true
                        },
                        email:
                        {
                            ignoreDefaultValues: true,
                            required: true
                        }
                }
            })) {
                alert("NOT VALID!");
            } 


       else 
          {
          alert("IS VALID!");
            //todo: ajax post to server
        }
    });
```

Here is an example of an input element

```
<input type="text" class="firstname" name="firstname" data-val-default="Type your first name here" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" />
```

The jquery validation seems to ignore the rules. if i test for example by typing an empty space it will validate and alert "NOT VALID" but it just ignores my custom validation.

What am i doing wrong?

Have i missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the validation before the submit function.  So instead of doing `$(this).valid(...)` in your `submit` handler, instead do this beforehand:

```
$('form#contact-form').validate( { //your rules
    ,
    submitHandler:function(){
       alert('Is Valid!');
       $(this).submit(); //or submit via AJAX, or whatever you planned...
    },
    invalidHandler:function(){
       alert('Is not valid!');
    }
});
```